# Smart Contract selfdestruct

Tags: solidity

I am very new to Solidity, and playing around with testrpc and truffle.

One of the thing I would like to do is the self-destruct a contract. Because I do wish to be able to remote my contract during development phase, until it is stable.

```
contract HelloWorld {
    function sayHello() public pure returns (string) {
        return ("Hello World!");
    }

    function kill()  public {
        selfdestruct(address(this));
    }
}
```

I am manage to call sayHello() and kill() using truffle console. But the self-destruct doesn't seem to do anything. I am still able to call sayHello().

Wish this question is not too newbie.

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass address which will receive contracts balance in `selfdestruct` parameter, not the contracts address. And check that you are using `sendTransaction()` and not `call()` in you console method call.